# Inserting link into text creates unnecessary indentation

Tags: html, links

I'm trying to insert a link into my text on Wordpress via Elementor, but it is creating a new line after the linked word. How do I get it to run consecutively on one line? When creating it in Elementor it shows correctly, but on the webpage it has an extra space. [image: How it shows on the website]. [image: How it shows when I edit it]

Comment: Just means that your CSS is treating the link as a `display: block` element and thus clearing the right hand margin.  This is a CSS issue.